# Caratheodory's theorem for vectors in a cone

Tags: convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

I am studying the book "matching theory" by Lovasz and Plummer, and I found the following statement (page 257):

[image]

Comparing it with [Caratheodory's theorem in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)) reveals two differences:

- The book speaks about vectors in a cone, particularly, in the *conic hull* of some given vectors. Wikipedia speaks about vectors in the *convex hull* of some given vectors.
- The book says that $n$ vectors are sufficient, where $n$ is the dimension of the space. Wikipedia says that $n+1$ vectors are sufficient.

I could not find an explicit statement of Caratheodory's theorem for the conic hull elsewhere. Does it easily follow from the theorem for convex hull?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume that if states that if a cone $C$ in $\Bbb R^n$ (or any $n$-dimensional
real vector space)
is generated by a set $S$,
then each element of $C$ is a non-negative linear combination of at most $n$ vectors
in $S$.

I'm not sure anyone else uses the term *conic hull* but it makes sense to define it as the set
of non-negative linear combinations of the vectors in question.

One can prove this Caratheodory-type result by the same method as the usual one.
Let $u\in C$ and suppose $u=\sum_{i=1}^m a_i v_i$ is a minimal representation of $u$
with $a_i>0$ and $v_i\in S$. If $m>n$ then there is a linear dependence
$0=\sum_{i=1}^m b_i v_i$ and then for a suitable choice of $\lambda$,
$u=\sum_{i=1}^m (a_i+\lambda b_i) v_i$ has non-negative coefficients one of which
vanishes, contradicting minimality.

Comment: Why do we need $n+1$ vectors for the convex hull version but only $n$ vectors for the conic hull version?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Well, in $\Bbb R^n$ there are sets of $n$ linearly independent vectors but no sets of $n+1$ linearly independent vectors, but there are sets of $n+1$ affinely independent vectors but no sets of $n+2$ affinely dependent vectors.